# Javascript - streamlining code

Tags: javascript

I've created a rough version of a site that will pull and display hundreds of pdfs. I want to be able to bookmark each pdf once the user clicks on it. The only way I could think of doing this is the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".pdf1").click(function(){
        if ($('#bookmark1').is(':visible')) {
                $("#bookmark1").css("display", "none");
            } else {
                $("#bookmark1").css("display", "inline");
            }                       
      });

      $(".pdf2").click(function(){
        if ($('#bookmark2').is(':visible')) {
                $("#bookmark2").css("display", "none");
            } else {
                $("#bookmark2").css("display", "inline");
            }
      });

      $(".pdf3").click(function(){
        if ($('#bookmark3').is(':visible')) {
                $("#bookmark3").css("display", "none");
            } else {
                $("#bookmark3").css("display", "inline");
            }
      });

      $(".pdf4").click(function(){
        if ($('#bookmark4').is(':visible')) {
                $("#bookmark4").css("display", "none");
            } else {
                $("#bookmark4").css("display", "inline");
            }
      });
    });
</script>
```

This isn't the best because I don't want to have to create over a hundred versions of the code above with different ids for each.

Is there any way the code can be changed so that I don't have to duplicate this so many times?

Comment: Since everything is sequentially numbered... Have you considered using loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the class to simply `pdf` (or anything else that's the same for all the elements), then use an HTML5 `data-*` attribute to link each specific one to a bookmark element:

```
<a href="#" class="pdf" data-bookmark="bookmark1">Click me</a>
<div id="bookmark1">Some content</div>
```

Then the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pdf').click(function(e) {
        var bookmarkId = $(this).attr('data-bookmark');
        var bookmark = $('#' + bookmarkId);
        if(bookmark.is(':visible')) {
            bookmark.css('display', 'none');
        }
        else {
            bookmark.css('display', 'inline');
        }
    });
});
```

Or, since you've got hundreds of elements, a single delegated event handler may be the better option:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pdf', function(e) {
    var bookmarkId = $(this).attr('data-bookmark');
    var bookmark = $('#' + bookmarkId);
    if(bookmark.is(':visible')) {
        bookmark.css('display', 'none');
    }
    else {
        bookmark.css('display', 'inline');
    }
});
```

Ideally you'd select an element that contains all of the `.pdf` elements and is as close to them in the DOM as possible, rather than using `document`. If you go for something other than `document` you'll also need to wrap it in a DOM ready (`$(document).ready()`) handler.

Comment: If you know how the elements are arranged, you could use something like `$(this).next()` to find the bookmark for any given pdf button.

Comment: @LeeMeador Yes, you could. However, I don't know the elements are arranged, and DOM traversal may be slower than linking one element to another by storing an ID in a data attribute. This has the benefit of not being tied to the DOM structure at all.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I tried implementing you code and found that the bookmark only appeared on the first image and wouldn't appear on any other images. If I have sometime later today I'll put together a jsfiddle to demonstrate what's happening.

Comment: @michelle The `data-bookmark` attribute on each of the elements has the correct value, yes? Other than that I can't think of any reason it would only work on the first image and not the others.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist here is the jsfiddle for what I currently have [(click here)](http://jsfiddle.net/michelleali/MvXRL/) and the one that you were suggesting [(click here)](http://jsfiddle.net/michelleali/Z5qdT/1/). I'm new to jsfiddle and I can't seem to get either one of the links above to work the way they do on my computer.

Comment: @michelle If you want to use jQuery you have to select it as the framework in the top left.

Comment: @michelle Ok, looked at the jsFiddle you provided. The `class="pdf"` and `data-bookmark="bookmarkX"` need to be on the same element; you have the class on the `<div>`, then the `data-bookmark` on the `<img>`, so it wouldn't work with the code I've suggested as it is currently. You either need to move the `class` (make sure it's just `pdf`, not `pdf1`, `pdf2` etc) to the `<img>` or the `data-bookmark` to the `<div>`. Take a look at [this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5qdT/2/).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I feel like a complete idiot here, even with your jsfiddle, i can't seem to get it working. I created a [test page](http://nova.capris.net/michelle/marketingLibrary2/test.html) based off of your code and its still not working. I'm sorry for not getting this. As I'm sure you can tell I'm pretty new at all of this. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: @michelle I didn't include it in my answer (but perhaps should have) since you already had it in the question, but you need to keep the `$(document).ready(function() {})` around it so that it runs after the DOM has been constructed. Otherwise it all looks fine.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist IT WORKED! Thank you so much! You have no idea how much I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Loop over them by a class with jquery and then fetch the id through the $(this) object like so:

```
$( ".pdf" ).each(function() {
    alert(this.id); // will contain the id of each pdf
});
```

You can then use those id's for your bookmaking of individual pdf's.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (var i = 1 ; i < 5 ; ++i) {
    $(".pdf" + i).click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("class");
        id = "#bookmark" + id.substring(3);
        if ($(id).is(':visible')) {
                $(id).css("display", "none");
            } else {
                $(id).css("display", "inline");
            }                       
    });
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjNRc/3/) based off the fiddle by @AnthonyGrist :

Comment: You have the same issue as Chris Cooper's (now deleted) answer, in that `i` won't be the correct value in the event handler functions because of the way scoping in JavaScript works. Here's the [illustrative jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SjNRc/) I posted on his answer.

Comment: We could build a closure to hold the value of i. I'd done something a little different now.